# How to show chrome's main menu?

Tags: google-chrome

My Chrome has no main menu (File, Edit, View, History, etc) on Windows 11. What's problem with it, and how can I get it back? There is no clue in settings.

Comment: Maybe they did the same Firefox and Thunderbird did a long time ago, which only show the menu if you press Alt.

Comment: Yes, Edge has no main menu either. I pressed Alt, nothing happened.